# redirect user to login page on the other device after calling AdminUserGlobalSignOut Cognito api from one

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I have logged into my web application using the same user on desktop and mobile. On calling AdminUserGlobalLogout for the user logged into web application, the refresh token is revoked. The user is redirected to login page as well.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-19', region: process.env.REGION });

    var params = {
  UserPoolId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Username: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminUserGlobalSignOut(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Refresh token does not work for the user logged in to the web app on mobile as well. But he is not redirected to login page in this case. How can I force redirect user to the login page in all devices ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `logout` logic has to be handled at the client app level be it `web app` or `mobile native`.

You can achieve this by either creating a `handler` such that on next `user event` it checks `auth` status and logs the user out or by running a scheduled `worker` which checks the `auth` status in background and take action accordingly.

If you are using `aws-amplify` with `cognito`, it has the UI Library with [Authenticator](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator) component, which can also be leveraged

Comment: yes we are using `aws-amplify` library. So, after making a server side call to `AdminUserGlobalSignout`, will call `Auth.signOut({global: true})`.

Comment: only calling `Auth.signOut({global: true})` should be sufficient, are you using `Authenticator` component ?

Comment: No, we are not using `Authenticator` component, but `Auth` class from aws-amplify. Calling `Auth.signOut({global: true})` should redirect user to login page, i think.

Comment: redirect won't happen automatically, you have to trigger it. If you had used  `Authenticator` then it would have happened automatically.

Comment: ok, will redirect the user when `idToken` and `accessToken` is not getting generated from refresh token, just before an API call is made.

Comment: no, you don't have to check using `refresh token`. You can use [currentAuthenticatedUser](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/#retrieve-current-authenticated-user) to check `auth` status

Comment: ok, if `currentAuthenticatedUser` errors out, we can redirect user to the login page.